# How access HeaderView in ListView?

Tags: android-listview

There is a method

> addHeaderView

Several headers can be added and I can get counter of them, but I do not see how can I get the view back. There is no method getHeaderView(int index), did I miss something?

My answer could be cache the view in ListView tag but maybe you can give me something more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exists a native implementation for it but you can use the adapter to manipulate the header as describe these links:

[Section header listview](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html)

[Listview with section header](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android)

```
 public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   public class PojoHeader {}

   public class PojoView {}

   private final int TYPE_HEADER     = 0;
   private final int TYPE_VIEW       = 0;
   private final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

   List<Object>      mList;

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return this.mList.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem( final int position ) {
       return this.mList.get( position );
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId( final int position ) {
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType( final int position ) {

       if ( this.mList.get( position ) instanceof PojoHeader ) {
           return this.TYPE_HEADER;
       }

       else if ( this.mList.get( position ) instanceof PojoHeader ) {
           return this.TYPE_VIEW;
       }

       return super.getItemViewType( position );
   }

   @Override
   public View getView( final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent ) {
       // Your view
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int getViewTypeCount() {
       return this.VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled( final int position ) {

       if ( this.mList.get( position ) instanceof PojoHeader ) {
           return false;
       }

       else if ( this.mList.get( position ) instanceof PojoHeader ) {
           return true;
       }

       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip I looked in sources and I can access header using something like listView.getAdapter().getView(hdrIdx, null, null);